# How to use generic rest element with tuple types?

Tags: typescript, variadic-tuple-types

TypeScript is giving me an error with a generic tuples rest element

```
type Tuple<Value extends any[]> = [...Value];
```

Error:

```
$ tsc
src/index.ts:1:36 - error TS2574: A rest element type must be an array type.

1 type Tuple<Value extends any[]> = [...Value];
```

What am I missing here?

- typescript version: `typescript@3.1.6`

---

```
type Tuple<HEAD, TAIL extends any[]> = [HEAD, ...TAIL];
```

doesn't work, although this works:

```
type Tuple<Value extends any[]> = [...any[]];
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?  How is `[...Value]` different from `Value`?

Comment: I was trying to make a Head and Tail generic types, but they don't work neither, so this should work in order for the rest to work, I'll update with what I was trying to accomplish

Comment: You can't use the spread operator on a type.

Comment: why ?, it works here `function tuple<T extends any[]>(...arg: T) {}`

Comment: There you are not using the spread operator on a type, but on an argument of type `T`.

Comment: @DenisFrezzato the type `[string, ...number[]]` is valid.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**UPDATE for TS4.0+.  TypeScript 4.0 introduced support for [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types), so the code in this question should work as written, without needing to reword your operation in terms of function parameters.  Hooray!**

---

TS3.9- ANSWER:

The only thing you're missing is that such inference [isn't currently supported](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25719).  Maybe it will be in a future version of TypeScript.  Luckily there is still a way to do what you want by expressing the desired operation in terms of one on [function parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#generic-rest-parameters), since as of TypeScript 3.0, there is a way to convert between tuple/array types and function parameters, and you can use `infer` as desired on parameter types.

Here's one possible implementation of `Tail`:

```
type Tail<T extends any[]> = 
  ((...t: T) => void) extends ((x: any, ...u: infer U) => void) ? U : never;

type TestTail = Tail<[1,2,3,4]>; // [2,3,4]
```

Notice that you take the tuple/array type `T`, spread it to a parameter list, then infer everything after the first parameter as another tuple/array rest type.

Similarly, you can implement your `Tuple` in a way that I'd call [`Cons`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons):

```
type Cons<H, T extends any[]> = 
  ((h: H, ...t: T) => void) extends ((...u: infer U) => void) ? U : never;

type TestCons = Cons<string, [number, boolean]>; // [string, number, boolean]
```

And I'll leave `Head` as an exercise for you (that's what people say when they want to seem smart instead of lazy).

Anyway, hope that helps you make progress.  Good luck!

Comment: thanks, I was hopping I could do something like ```type Tuple<Head, Tail extends any[]> = [Head, ...Tail];
type Head<T> = T extends Tuple<infer H, any[]> ? H : never;
type Tail<T> = T extends Tuple<any, R> ? R : never;
```, but oh well