# Remove the first element of a tuple

Tags: typescript

If I have:

```js
const selector = (state: {}, count = 1) => {};
type parms = Parameters<typeof selector>;
```

then `parms` will be:

```
[{}, number?]
```

I note if I apply an index I can extract a single param:

```
type parms = Parameters<typeof selector>[1]; // type parms = number
```

Is there some way to indicate I would like to omit the first parameter from being returned? Something along the lines of `.slice(1)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [typescript generic tuples error rest element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53356652/typescript-generic-tuples-error-rest-element)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For the specific case of "remove the first element from a tuple", you can use  [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) as introduced in TypeScript 4.0:

```
type Tail<T extends any[]> = T extends [infer A, ...infer R] ? R : never;
```

Before 4.0 you could do it with [generic rest parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#generic-rest-parameters):

```
type Tail<T extends any[]> = 
  ((...x: T) => void) extends ((h: infer A, ...t: infer R) => void) ? R : never;
```

Either way gives you the desired behavior:

```
type Test = Tail<[1,2,3,4,5]>; // [2,3,4,5]
type Parms = Tail<Parameters<typeof selector>>; // [number?]
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgSwDYB4ZQgD2BAdgEwGco5cQBtAXQD4oBeWDbPIqchXAMwgCcoBBADRQAdGI7c+AJUpQA-FClQAXFFwQAbrwDcAWABQB0JFgRCwerESpyARmEAmYQGZhAFmEBWGtqgB6PzYnVw9vAwBjAHtccyhCCCQIcOBIvgYACnM4HFUAbwBfYSiAV1wLBlsASnpaXKh8vX1jaAAFOB4AW2IGeGQUNp44DogcHkIUZsjOOISklJ5qal8AtlxijoAjXjlKAyA)

Comment: Thanks @jcalz, this works, but I admit I'm finding it a little dense. It appears that you infer the first param and then infer the rest with the spread, but to do so we must check to see if the `(...x: T) => void)` fat arrow function extends `(h: infer A, ...t: infer R) => void)` Is there somewhere where I can find this concept explained?

Comment: This is using [type inference in conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) to pull out the rest type.  We don't really want to do a check (we *know* that the check will pass); it's just that conditional types are the only handle TypeScript gives to perform such inference.

Comment: What I especially like is that I can also adjust the above to `h: State` to ensure that the function I am `Tail`ing is conforming to my expectations about what the first parameter should be. Thanks again!