# how to reference all parameters except first in typescript

Tags: typescript

I would like to reference one function's parameter types in another function, but only use a subset of them.

```
//params of bar should be same as foo, except p1 should be a different type

function foo(p1: string, p2: number, p3: boolean){
 ...
}

//i'd like to do something like this, though it's obviously not valid syntax
function bar(p1: string[], ...rest: Parameters<typeof foo>.slice(1)){
}
```

Is there a way to do that? Obviously it's not hard to do manually with only 3 parameters, but in my actual code I have more parameters and I'd like to not repeat them.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[TypeScript 4.0 +](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-0/)

#### Option 1: Variadic tuple

```
type DropFirst<T extends unknown[]> = T extends [any, ...infer U] ? U : never

function bar(p1: string[], ...rest: DropFirst<Parameters<typeof foo>>) { }
// bar: (p1: string[], p2: number, p3: boolean) => void
```

Syntax for inferring all tuple elements except the first one now has become simpler. See Robby Cornelissen's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63024984/5669456) for versions < 4.0.

#### Option 2: Labeled Tuple Elements

```
type CommonParams = [p2: number, p3: boolean];

function foo2(p1: string, ...rest: CommonParams){} 
// foo2: (p1: string, p2: number, p3: boolean) => void
function bar2(p1: string[], ...rest: CommonParams) { }
// bar2: (p1: string[], p2: number, p3: boolean) => void
```

Named tuples can be used to preserve function parameter names, so there is no lossy conversion.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTBQIAgeQBwFwJYHsB2ECMAuCA1AhgE4J4AmCAxhHAK4wA2AplQJ4wPhigBm1K5iqCFyRIAFDCwQAznCIoA5gBoIMAEzYU1ALYAjBgWUwAzNh0jGeFAEoIAbwgBfUHFZMAIgSQwAYggIyAHgAVCAYADzgGFBIpCF4AaxQkAHcUAG0AXQA+CABeCBDwyOjYtMtmZQA6aoQULn0IAFUMiAB+JogNBgA3fQBubl5+ZDQdQnFJGTl5TKrqggYZbA8vX384AIAFQjwtBkj-AJc2JC4hESysm3snSB4+AVHxiWwp2pmMw3UITV19QxMEDMSAs1mw3SQCBIoA4HGg8BGEG+ADldgwSFRaIxYc5XBAAMJILRaVDbAi7WL5NJqDTaPQGFSA4GgjJ9CCQGA7PYHH5o2KEJgwBZSfS9aGDB6I4RIVQTV6yd5zSrCuDYQnE0lcqRWWwOCBw6XfOXSBUKL60v4M4ymcwMSw2XI5CFQiXDQRjAiyl4m6azCDVZWLVUEokklBkinXRxwj1G71vBR+mk-On-Rk2kF26x5J2QkhAA)

Comment: I think option 1 would need to be `type DropFirst<T extends unknown[]> = T extends [any, ...infer U][] ? U[] : never` (to avoid the error about rest params needing to be an array type)

but that makes every parameter in U the union of all parameter types, rather than restricting each param to the right type

Comment: Not sure, what you are meaning, can you give an example? If you wanted to assert, that `DropFirst` always spits out an array type, you could define it like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=4.0.0-beta&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=93#code/C4TwDgpgBAIgTgezAMQJZwM7ADwBUoQAewEAdgCYZQDaArqQNakIDupANFAHQ-1OulqAXSEA+KAF4o+IiQpVqAQ1IhOPLqlIAzCHCgBVIVAD8BqAC4opCADddAbgBQoSLEQp0WAIyS3SNJg4wqLO4NDw-p7AAEy+ER6B2NReYqGu8QFYAMxx7plBXuzRqUA): `type DropFirst<T extends [unknown, ...unknown[]]> = T extends [any, ...infer U] ? U : never;`

Comment: oh sorry my mistake. I was accidentally on typescript 3.9. Switching to 4.0 does indeed make it work like you originally described. Thanks!

Comment: when trying to use `rest` I get
`Type 'never' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.ts(2488)`

Comment: @JohnSnow sounds like the type resolution of the passed in value went wrong

Answer (score 4):

You can create a type tuple using the [`Parameters`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterst) utility type, and then create a new type from that, omitting the first type:

```
type Rest<T extends any[]> = 
  ((...p: T) => void) extends ((p1: infer P1, ...rest: infer R) => void) ? R : never;

function foo(p1: string, p2: number, p3: boolean) {
}

function bar(p1: string[], ...rest: Rest<Parameters<typeof foo>>) {
}


bar([''], 0, true); // ok
bar('', 0, true); // error
bar([''], true, 0); // error
```

---

<sup>See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55344670/remove-item-from-inferred-paramters-tuple).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You would use [Destructured Object Parameters](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/typing-destructured-object-parameters-in-typescript).
By passing an object into a function, you can select to only use a subset of the fields of that parameter object.

You can define the parameter interface type separately (as with `foo` below), or you can define it inline (like in `bar` below).

You can then pass the same object (containing your parameters as fields) into both, and the functions would only select what they need.

```
type FooParameters = { p1: string, p2: number, p3: boolean }
function foo({ p1, p2, p3 }: FooParameters) {
  console.log("From foo:", p1, p2, p3)
}

//i'd like to do something like this, though it's obviously not valid syntax
function bar({ p1 }: { p1: string }) {
  console.log("From bar:", p1)
}

const parameters = { p1: "First Parameter", p2: 2, p3: false }

foo(parameters)
bar(parameters)
```

Comment: yea an object would be simpler, though unfortunately I'm typing an existing method and don't want to change the signature

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method would be to have a shared rest parameter type:

```
type SharedParams = [number, boolean];

//params of bar should be same as foo, except p1 should be a different type

function foo(p1: string, [p2, p3]: SharedParams){
    ...
}

//i'd like to do something like this, though it's obviously not valid syntax
function bar(p1: string[], ...rest: SharedParams){
    ...
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=7&ssc=77&pln=6&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAygFgQwE4QCYAVkILYGcoC8UA2gHYCu2ARhEgDRRUD2TANhAqQLoDcAsAChBggGblSAY2ABLJqSgiWACjABGAFxRcwJNNIBzBsTAAmBmADMXTfGRpMSHLgCUAb0EBfYQLGSZcxmQVDS0dPX1iLgYAOliUbRtEFAwsPDdPIA)

Comment: Ah yea extracting it does work well, though one limitation is that the variables lose their names in the type definitions if you spread the array. `foo(p1: string, __1_0: number, __1_1: boolean): void` is what I see when I do that