# Typescript instantiate string union type

Tags: javascript, typescript

So I have a string union type

```
type S = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';
```

I want to initialize a value of type S, while asserting that is of type S. With a variable, it's very easy:

```
const s1: S = 'a';
const s2: S = 'z'; // error
```

However, I just want to instantiate the value itself, along the lines of `'a' as S` but *checking* that `'a'` is of type `S`.

The exact use case is that I'm using a library that provides a function `f(s: string)`, but I want to ensure that when I call it, I only call it with the strings I deem ok. Since [afaik] you can't narrow the signature from outside the library, I was thinking of doing something like `f('a' as S)` every time I used `f`.

Defining my own function `g = (s: S) => f(s)` isn't a great option because actually `f`'s signature looks like `f(s: string, t: T)` where `T` is a complex, library defined type that I'm not sure is even exported.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the external function with your own using the string type ([TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ssl=5&ssc=79&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgDynATmAhgGwGJhgXhgB4AVAPgAoIAuGaFASzAHMAaGKWkgSgLI4CwAKGFQAngAc4MAMoEYAcnQKYAH0UAjFeoXAFAbmHDQkWGJABXFLnlVaM9pxgAFdCnQBbOMhQQi4qRAAM3gkVAwcMDIAbQBGAF1efH5EHwjcKkduIA)):

```
const externalFn = <T>(s: string, t: T) => t

type S = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';

const yourFn = (s: S, t: Parameters<typeof externalFn>[1]) => externalFn(s, t)
```

If you need to handle a function with more than one argument, you can use the idea in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63029283/5157454) ([TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAIgTgezAMQJZwM7ADwBUoQAewEAdgCYZQCupA1qQgO6kDaAugHxQC8U%20REhSqsAhqRAAaKADo5qUgDMIcKAFV2UAPzqoALiikIANxUBYAFCWAxglJYCxFaVEAbZKV5Q8nABQYDLDgFAHNpYANcAEpebmBLS1BIKABlLwByUXSoAB8odIAjbLz063SAbgSLW3tgKBAEajgPL38DFOk5GTgILAN4JDRMHAAFUThRAFsIEkxsJIgERUdZl3dSTk4Ynm5BZzcPf065HqwooA)):

```
type DropFirst<T extends unknown[]> = T extends [any, ...infer U] ? U : never

const externalFn = <T>(s: string, t: T) => t

type S = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';

const yourFn = (s: S, ...rest: DropFirst<Parameters<typeof externalFn>>) => externalFn(s, ...rest)
```

Comment: Ah sorry I just edited my post so I wouldn't get this answer :/

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: thanks! In the case where `f` has multiple such parameters, is there an extensible solution?

Comment: links seem to be broken now

Comment: See these answers -https://stackoverflow.com/a/67605309/5157454, https://stackoverflow.com/a/63029283/5157454

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making a simple wrapper function like so:

```
function ok<T extends string>(s: T): T {
  return s;
}
```

that I could then use like `f(ok<S>('a'))`, because in my case there were multiple functions and types that I wanted to do this verification for, and making a separate wrapping function would be tedious and not maintainable.

Comment: side note: Initially, intellij was giving me autocomplete suggestions for these strings (they were actually template literal types)--then I did something (I wish I knew what) and now it stopped :( Does anyone know how to ensure intellij is autocompleting them?

Comment: it was because there were too many possibilities for my template literals