# Is there a reasonable way to type 'the nonnegative integers smaller than n' in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I like Typescript very much but am still just learning, I don't really care about applications, I just want to know what can and can't be typed.

One thing I would like to type is the (real) numbers between 0 and 1, but I think this is likely too much to ask so I set my sights on just the whole numbers between 0 and n.

I came up with this

```
type ExtendArray<E, T extends any[]> = ((fst: E, ...rest: T) => any) extends (
    ...rest: infer U
) => any
    ? U
    : T;

type UpTo<N extends number, K extends number[] = []> = {
    0: UpTo<N, ExtendArray<K["length"], K>>;
    1: K;
}[K["length"] extends N ? 1 : 0];

type UnwrapArray<Arr extends any[]> = Arr extends Array<infer R> ? R : never;

type NUMS = UnwrapArray<UpTo<10>>;
```

Super, the type NUMS is 0 | 1 | ... | 9 which is what I wanted.

But if I replace 10 with 100 I get a problem 'Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite', fair enough, my implementation is pretty complicated its fair to say.

My question isn't about the error, I think that's reasonable, rather, is there a good way to type what I want that doesn't run into this limitation?

A good way should let me get the numbers up to say 20000

As a sort of side note, I find myself doing lots of this trickery where I use function types just to express what I want to do (as in ExtendArray), is this legitimate (i.e. is it the way people typically are doing things?)

Comment: See [microsoft/TypeScript#15480](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15480)

Comment: Brilliant. I see the idea, it may take some time to properly digest and it doesn't quite 'look' or 'act' the way I wanted it to, I will need to reflect on whether this is truly equivalent to what I want.

Comment: 20000 is pretty horrendous, btw... even a single union with 20K members will start to tank your compiler performance.  You can generate one yourself fairly easily by pasting the results of `console.log("type LessThan20K ="+new Array(20000).fill(0).map((_,j)=>j+(j%100?"":"\n")).join("|")+";");` into your IDE and see how it starts dragging to use it.  Unions seem to perform well up to hundreds of members, not thousands.  Since you have no actual use case it's hard to suggest how to proceed.

Comment: Your `ExtendArray`, which I'd call `Cons` is currently the best way to do that (relevant [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53356755/2887218)); arbitrary tuple spread/concat isn't directly supported yet, see [microsoft/TypeScript#5453](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453)